# Canon's .CR3 - No Raw Editor on Ubuntu supports?

Tags: file-format

Please note, that format in context here is Canon's relatively new .CR3

This:

[image: .CR3 file format]

I'm either not searching with the right words, or support for .CR3 from Canon camera's like the M50 (that I have) doesn't exist for any RAW editor on Linux (using Ubuntu).

RawTherapee, GIMP, Darktable, none supports the relatively new .CR3 format from Canon.

I currently have a Windows 10 in Virtualbox with only *one* purpose, namely, to run Canon's DPP.

Is there no CR3 support on any RAW Editor that runs on Linux?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: According to [the discussion on this issue](https://github.com/darktable-org/rawspeed/issues/121)  some people are working to get CR3 support on Linux. But as Canon doesn't support Linux and doesn't provide them any information about the file format that may take some time.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this is a libexiv2 issue... see here: https://github.com/Exiv2/exiv2/releases/tag/v0.27.4 . The latest Ubuntu still has the Version 0.27.3-3 which has not yet support for CR3

Answer (score 3):

There is no editor with cr3 support at the moment. You have to wait for some updates.
In the meantime you have to use the Canon DPP.

Answer (score 0):

Use play on Linux an easy (wine) install and setup app to allow you to install Adobe DNG and covert them in Ubuntu for use in mentioned apps.

```
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

Download Adobe DNG https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/adobe-dng-converter.html

Install with playonlinux make sure to make app draw .desktop within playonlinux app.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I think Darktable even now supports .CR3, after more than a year the format came out. I'll check out the Play on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Use ART as explained in here : https://garridodiaz.com/canon-cr3-support-in-linux-using-art-rawtherapee-clone/.

We can install it through repository by adding ppa below, update, and then install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install art
```

Answer (score 0):

CR3 files are RAW image files produced by newer Canon digital cameras. To open .cr3 files in Ubuntu, you need an image viewer that supports this format.

I'm using rawtherapee editor.

```
sudo apt-get install rawtherapee
```